# OnClick in design mode

Tags: c#, winforms, designmode

sorry my english language is bad

I want make a button by another control and this button editable in design mode (change size, define onclick,... )

i create a button in design mode by programming but onclick of this not work in design time

`btnTest.Click += new System.EventHandler(this._Click);`

```
protected void _Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DesignMode)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi Design Mode.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi Run Mode.");
    }
}
```

don't show show message

Comment: In fact this is not supported and it will be never supported, no one need such a feature except you?

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to understand what are you putting in the condition. read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.designmode.aspx) on `Control.DesignMode` Property:

> Gets a value indicating whether a control is being used on a design
>   surface.

The `DesignMode` property will be set to True when you are editing your winform page in Visual Studio. For example if you create a user control you could show a user control based on dummy data during design-time and at run-time generate a user control based on the provided data

i don't think you can push a button in designer time so this code does nothing i'm afraid